# How can I convert a React Component to string or HTML, inside a map function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

How can I convert a React Component to string or HTML, inside a map function?

I´m working on a project that I built in SSR (server side rendering) architecture. I´m relatively new to React / Node architecture and I know I´ll need to refactor my code in order to follow good practices. But for now, I´m trying to do things the way I understand it better.

Here´s the basic scenario:

I´m working on a subcomponent that maps an array:

(some code)

```
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import FrontendContent from "./frontend-content-cb-component.js";
```

(some code)

Inside the render method, summing it up, I´ve something like this:

```
render(){
    return(
        { arrPublicationsListing.map((publicationsRow, publicationsRowKey) =>{
            return (
                <FrontendContent key={publicationsRowKey} 
                      idParentContent={ publicationsRow.id } 
                      idTbContent={ "" } 
                      contentType={ 3 } 
                      configLayoutType={ 2 } 
                      configContentNRecords={ "" } 
                      configContentSort={ "" }>
                </FrontendContent>
            );
       })}
   );
}
```

Up til now, this is working as its supposed to. The thing is that I need the content from  to be a string because I´m going to do something with it.
Note:  is a complex component that does some API fetch and so on. But is working fine in this setup.

So, I researched a bit and tried this way:

```
render(){
    return(
        { arrPublicationsListing.map((publicationsRow, publicationsRowKey) =>{
            return (
                { ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<FrontendContent key={publicationsRowKey} 
                      idParentContent={ publicationsRow.id } 
                      idTbContent={ "" } 
                      contentType={ 3 } 
                      configLayoutType={ 2 } 
                      configContentNRecords={ "" } 
                      configContentSort={ "" }>
                 </FrontendContent>) }
            );
       })}
   );
}
```

It didn’t render and returned a strange error. Any ideas on how I could accomplish this? Is there another method I should try? I´d like to stick to the idea of iterating inside the render return.

Thanks,

Comment: I am not sure how it is working as expected, in the first case, since you're not returning anything inside of the map callback. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-playground-forked-r2nyx) is an example of you're supposed to do it

Comment: oh, sorry...there´s a part missing. I´m gonna edit.

Comment: If you need the content to be a string, you're doing it wrong. If you need to manipulate the child component in some fashion, you do so by changing the data passed to it and amending how it processes that data.